# Disable Problems badge in VScode tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

What I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuvpP.png) badge that appears in tabs.

As far as I can tell it indicates the number of errors in a document. I've tried to remove it but I can't find the correct setting to turn it off (if it exists).

Comment: try Workbench > Editor > Decorations: Badges  in settings

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you!